# Using achartengine, how can I set the x-axis values without using x labels?

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

For my Android application, I need to have the x-axis represent a frequency axis. Currently, I am using myRenderer.setXlabels() for the time being. However, that is not efficient  enough for my application because once the min and max x-axis labels are set, if you zoom out of the graph, there are no x-axis values to the left of the min X label and to the right of the max X label. Also, if you zoom in, there only exists the x-axis values that I explicitly had the program label. Hence, if you zoom in at least 2 times, there are no x-axis values shown = :(

In the AChartEngine Demo application, they have a trigonometric functions example where they plot a sin and cos wave from 0 to 360 degrees. Similar to this example, I would like my frequency axis to go from 0 to half the sampling frequency, which is 22050 (22.05e3), such that if you zoom in or out, there always exists x-axis values relative to the data points.

The amount of data points I will be plotting will be typically very large (roughly speaking between 10,000 - 40,000 points), but I only need one line (or series) of data plotted in the graph at a time.

If anyone knows how to do this without using labels, I would appreciate it. :)

---

### UPDATE (w/ example):

**BELOW** - Matlab code to represent what I mean by frequency axis:

```
x = [0 5 -5 3 -3 1 -1 0];
X = fft(x);
absX = abs(X);
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(abs_X)
title('(a) General x-axis')

freq_axis = linspace(0,22.05e3,8);
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(freq_axis,abs_X)
title('(b) Frequency x-axis (Linearly-spaced)')
```

By Matlab definition:

**linspace** - Linearly spaced vector.
  **linspace(X1, X2)** generates a row vector of 100 linearly equally spaced points between X1 and X2.

**linspace(X1, X2, N)** generates N points between X1 and X2.
  For N = 1, linspace returns X2.

[image: (a) general x-axis (time domain), (b) linearly-spaced frequency x-axis (frequency domain)]

So in simpler context, I just want to figure out how I can change the x-axis values to represent other numerical values (convert from time domain x-values to frequency domain x-axis values).

Comment: I think you should add a screenshot or something to explain what you need.

Comment: I attempted to add an image, but apparently I don't have enough 'reputation points' to be allowed to post images. So perhaps if you have Matlab, you could just copy the piece of code above and run the script to visually understand what I am trying to implement using the AChartEngine library.

Comment: Try to add an image now. I don't want to have Matlab.

Comment: Thank you. Hope that picture helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved my own problem. And since I couldn't find much help on stackoverflow.com prior to posting this question, I will provide my solution incase anyone else is curious about **how you can change the numerical values on the x (or y) axis**.

```
/**
* sampling frequency
*/
private final int fs = 44100;

/**
* last x-value, (starting x-value = 0)
*/
private final int endValue = fs/2;

public XYMultipleSeriesDataset getFrequencyAxis(double[] fftData) {
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset rangeData = new  XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

    String[] titles  = new String[] { "FFT data" };     // titles of data
    List<double[]> xAxis = new ArrayList<double[]>(1);  // x-axis values
    List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>(1); // y-axis values

    // Need to have just as many x values as y values
    xAxis.add(new double[fftData.length]);  
    values.add(new double[fftData.length]);

    // Linearly-spaced x-axis values -> increment must be kept constant 
    double increment = (endValue)/fftData.length;  // (fs/2)/length of data
    for(int i =0; i < fftData.length; i++) {
        xAxis.get(0)[i] = i * increment;
        values.get(0)[i] = fftData[i];
    }

    // for the buildDataset method call:
    rangeData = dataBuilder(titles, xAxis, values);
    return rangeData;
}

private XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataBuilder(String[] titles,
        List<double[]> xValues, List<double[]> yValues) {

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset1 = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    addXYSeries(dataset1, titles, xValues, yValues, 0);
    return dataset1;
}

private void addXYSeries(XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset, String[] titles,
        List<double[]> xValues, List<double[]> yValues, int scale) {

    int length = titles.length; // # of series to add to plot
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

        // maps the x-axis values to their respective y-axis values
        double[] xV = xValues.get(i);
        XYSeries series = new XYSeries(titles[i], scale);
        double[] yV = yValues.get(i);
        int seriesLength = xV.length;
        for (int k = 0; k < seriesLength; k++) {
            series.add(xV[k], yV[k]);
        }
        dataset.addSeries(series);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add custom labels using:

```
renderer.addXTextLabel(x, "text");
```

If you only want custom labels then you can disable the default ones:

```
renderer.setXLabels(0);
```

Comment: I appreciate the advice, but what I was interested in implementing was actual axis values and not using Strings of text to label the axis values.

Comment: You can control that by playing with the setXLabels parameter.

Comment: The "setXLabels(int number)" works by making text labels with equal space (width) between each x-axis label. For example, I could say "setXLabels(8)" and the renderer would display 8 equally spaced x-axis values on the plot. However, using text labels (& removing regular x-axis values) ONLY displays text at the values specified, not for the entire axis. Therefore, if you zoom out, axis values do not exist. Similarly, if you zoom in, more specific values do not exist. However, I ended up figuring out the solution to my question and I've posted it below. If you are interested, check it out.

Comment: You can listen for pan and zoom events and update the custom labels on the fly. I don't see anything related to labels in your solution.

Comment: +1 `renderer.setXLabels(0);` is what I was looking for! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As told by [Dan in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15814046/1752560) you can use `renderer.addXTextLabel(x, "text");` to set x-axis values.

In your case::

You need frequency so try this ..

```
for(int i=0; i< x.Length; i++)
 {
   multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(i, Getfreq(x[i]));   
 }
```

where `Getfreq(x[i])` is another method to generate different frequency for different value of `x` and returns string to display on x-axis.

```
 public String Getfreq(int i)
 {
    //put the android code to calculate frequency
   freqxlable = Freq(i); //put actual function that will calculate frequency 
   Srting s = freqxlable +"":
   return s;
 }
```

Hope this will solve, if any issue comment on it...